# ngx-bootstrap datepicker withTimepicker bsconfig not working

Tags: datepicker, timepicker, ngx-bootstrap

It appears that the ngx-bootstrap withTimepicker: true option with bsConfig does not work.  I created a new angular 11 project then added bootstrap 5 and ngx-bootstrap 7.1.0.  I copy/pasted the code right out of the documentation example.  Datepicker works correctly, time selector does not appear as expected.  What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

it's available in ngx-bootstrap 7.1.2 on-wards, I also faced the same problem but after upgrading it's works fine.

Comment: Just a small clarification, the version is 7.1.2 (currently) not 7.2.0.

Comment: Mystery solved.  Partially.   I was npm installing @latest.   That would be 7.1.0 currently.  I had to specify 7.1.2.    This ngx-bootstrap datetime picker has a ux (user experience) flaw.  Just setting the time does not change the time.   There is no set button available.   One has to select the time along with the date.